# How to get rid of annoying border around buttons when changing the background of a window in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, button, border

I want to change the background of a window from Tkinter, but a white border is showing up around the button. I tried the bd=0 argument, but it only removed the bottom border piece, not the side border and top border. Could someone please help me get rid of the whole border? Thanks.

```
from tkinter import *
import os
window=Tk()
window.geometry("400x400")
window['background']='#9ed7c3'
def printt():
    print(2+2)
editbtn=Button(text='Edit Settings', command=printt, bd=0)
editbtn.pack()
```

Comment: Have you tried also setting `highlighthickness` to zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the default appearance of the `Button` widget.  You could use the `FLAT` option for the button appearance and make the background the same color as your window, but then it is very hard to tell that it is a button because you loose the border.

```
from tkinter import *
import os # this isn't being used


window = Tk()
window.geometry("400x400")
window['background']='#9ed7c3'


def printt():
    print(2+2)

    
editbtn = Button(text='Edit Settings', relief=FLAT, bg='#9ed7c3', command=printt )
editbtn.pack()


window.mainloop()
```

[image]